# Inter-container connection via localhost

Tags: docker

I would like to set up my containers so that they connect to each other via localhost.

My setup is a main application container and two other containers that it needs to connect to (ActiveMQ and Wiremock).

I already run ActiveMQ and Wiremock in containers with the relevant ports exposed, and the main application runs through IntelliJ and connects to these. However, when I am not developing the main applications, I would like to run it in a container for simplicity but it cannot connect to the ports exposed by the others.

Setting `--net=host` doesn't seem to work, nor does creating a network `docker network create <NAME>` and assigning it in the `docker run` with `--net=<NAME>`.

The application already runs in a container in other environments on the host network.

Comment: `doesn't seem to work`, what's the exact error? Connection refused, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docker creates a default network in which all containers run, and sets a network name for each of your containers, using the container name.

if you have a contained named `mq` for your ActiveMQ, then you would use something like `tcp://mq:61616` (or whatever protocol / port you have configured) from your other containers, to connect to it.

you shouldn't need to set the `--net` option unless you need to create a specific network for specific containers to use.

Comment: You can also link containers together, then ports will be available on localhost.